# Golang GIN errored when bind form data

Tags: go, go-gin

When I try the bind form-data request to struct, it errored as "fatal error: stack overflow".

Here is my codes. There is no thing to explain. I am start of code but cant solve the code.

struct

```golang
type Wish struct {
    ID                int                `gorm:"primarykey;autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt         time.Time          `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt         time.Time          `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt         gorm.DeletedAt     `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    UserID            int                `json:"user_id" form:"user_id"`
    User              *User              `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID" json:"user_data,omitempty"`
    WishTypeID        int                `json:"wish_type_id" form:"wish_type_id"`
    WishType          *WishType          `gorm:"foreignKey:WishTypeID" json:"wish_type_data,omitempty"`
    ProcessTrack      []*ProcessTrack    `gorm:"foreignKey:WishID" json:"process_track,omitempty"`
    VacationDateRange *VacationDateRange `gorm:"foreignKey:WishID" json:"vacation_date_range,omitempty"`
    Content           string             `gorm:"type:varchar(255)" json:"content" form:"content"`
    Status            WishStatus         `gorm:"type:integer" json:"status" form:"status"`
    Files             []*File            `gorm:"polymorphic:Module;polymorphicValue:wish_files" json:"files,omitempty"`
}
```

controller

```golang
var wish migrations.Wish
    if err := c.Bind(&wish); err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "Talep Okunamadı!"})
        return
    }
    c.JSON(200, wish)
    return
```

request

[image: form-data body]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified Controller

```golang
type Req struct {
        Content           string                        `form:"content"`
        WishTypeID        int                           `form:"wish_type_id"`
        VacationDateRange *migrations.VacationDateRange `form:"vacation_date_range"`
    }
    err, i, g := authorizer.AuthorizeIt(c, a.Subject, a.Action)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(i, g)
        return
    }
    var wishReq Req
    var wish migrations.Wish
    if err := c.Bind(&wishReq); err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "Wish can't bind."})
        return
    }
    wish.WishTypeID = wishReq.WishTypeID
    wish.Content = wishReq.Content
    wish.VacationDateRange = wishReq.VacationDateRange
```

But still I couldn't understand why is not working as first style. I add usual usage too. It usually works too.

```golang
err, i, g := authorizer.AuthorizeIt(c, a.Subject, a.Action)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(i, g)
        return
    }
    var announce mig.Announce

    err = c.Bind(&announce)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "Announce can't bind. Error Code: AN-CRT-20"})
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are binding the payload form-data to the struct is correct.
I've tried it myself and it works without issues (see image below).
Also, is your request only sending form data? Is there anything else going on?

Some tips:

- consider separating data access structs from API structs (less clutter in the tags, more secure as you prevent getting/sending undesired data)
- try removing fields one by one and test to see if you can isolate the problem (we don't see you other types so it's hard to replicate exactly)

[image]

Comment: I will try your tips

Comment: I did with seperate request struct. I will add answer too